# css: z-index not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place `#user_change_photo` on top of `#user_pic`, tried with `z-index`, but it doesn't work.

HTML

```
<div id="user_pic"><span><img id="pic" src=""></span></div>
<div id="user_change_photo">Change Photo</div>
```

CSS

```
<style>
#pic{
    background-color: orange;
    width:320px;
    height:258px;
    z-index: -1;
}
#user_pic{
    z-index: -1;

}
#user_change_photo{
    width:920px;
    background-color: red;
    color:black;
    margin-top: -50px;
    z-index: 1;

}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative;` for each selector with the `z-index` style